# Data type for radio buttons

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question about radio buttons and data type. I am creating a table as such:

```
   CREATE TABLE `countries`(  
     `name` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL ,  
     `population` SMALLINT NOT NULL ,  
     `latitude` TINYINT NOT NULL,
     `country_popularity` TINYINT NOT NULL
    );
```

Also, I have

```
    <form method="post" action="countryfact.php">

   <li>Q1. At what latitude can this country be found?
   <input type="radio" name="latitude" value="equator">Equator
   <input type="radio" name="latitude" value="capricorn">Capricorn
   <input type="radio" name="latitude" value="cancer">Cancer</li><br/>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

   </form>
```

My question is: can the data type TINYINT (or SMALLINT or INT) be used for a radio button with three different values which are strings (capricorn, cancer and equator)?

My second question is about sliders:

The slider above refers to the field "country_popularity" above, and I have used the data type "tinyint" for this. Am I correct in using tinyint for a value determined by a slider? This may be a trivial question for some of you, but may not be trivial for someone who does not have mastery of PHP/SQL.

Comment: TINYINT, SMALLINT or INT permit to store integer number. In your case, you would store string. The satatype to use in this case is VARCHAR2.

Comment: On a sidenote, if that is your actual HTML, it is invalid.

Comment: No, it's not the actual HTML. I lopped off large sections of my code to make it simpler to see.

Comment: I think you should just store it as either a CHAR or VARCHAR.  CHAR is better though as it can hold an integer value as well.

Answer (score 1):

About your first question :
TINYINT, SMALLINT or INT permit to store integer numbers. In your case, you would store string (equator, Capricorn, ...). The datatype to use in this case is VARCHAR2.

About your second question : 
The TINIYINT datatype permits to store numbers between 0 and 255. Is your slider values are in this range, yes you can use this datatype.

BTW, it is a good approach to avoid using overdimensioned datatype.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use an [enum](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splenum.php) for storing the radio results.

As far as sliders go, if your value has a floating point I'd go for Float \ Decimal, and not tinyint - but it really depends on the range of possible values.